# Controlling a PictureBox from a class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a little project in C#, (Windows Forms Application). I have on the form 77 PictureBoxes (pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3, ...) and I want to control them but from a new class (Access.cs), by declaring a new one picturebox in the class to control all the pictures.

Because it would be too long if I pass through each pictureBox and add a click method and Copy + Paste the code and change the pictureBox number each time.

I've set the pictures as public and tried the following code:

Access.cs:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Access
{
    PictureBox picBox = new PictureBox();

    public void PictureClicked()
    {
        picBox.Image = Properties.Resources.apple;
    }
}
```

Form1.cs:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Access ac = new Access();
    ac.PictureClicked();
}
```

but the code didn't work!!

Comment: And what happened when you tried that code? On a side note, why so many boxes? Do you really need all of them?

Comment: Why can't you just cast the sender object and send that as a parameter to your PictureClicked method?

Comment: the code didn't work .. unfortunately yes!!

Comment: You don't need the PictureBox that is declared inside class Access.  Just add some code to iterate over your controls and wire up the Click() event of all the found PictureBoxes to the event inside your class.  @SATSON showed how to use the "sender" parameter to determine which control fired the event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont really get what you want to do but you could try to send the object to your Access class:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Access ac = new Access();
    ac.PictureClicked(sender);
}


 public void PictureClicked(Object Sender)
{
           picBox = (PictureBox)Sender;
           picBox.Image = Properties.Resources.apple;
 }
```

Comment: after i wrote your code i declared this in the class : Form1 myForm = new Form1();
to use imageList1 from the form. but when i debug the program i get a StackOverFlowException. and when i start the program without debugging a window pops up telling me that the program has stopped working. Do you know why is that?!

Answer (score 1):

Access.Cs

```
 public void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PictureBox pi = (PictureBox)sender;

            pi.Image = Properties.Resources.alert__2_;
        }
```

Form1.Cs

```
 private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 c =new Form1();
            c.pictureBox1_Click(sender, e);


        }
```

Here pictureBox2_Click this event for all picturebox